# Looker cannot adjust spacing on visual

Tags: data-visualization, visualization, dashboard, looker

I have been unable to find a way to lock in the spacing of columns in a visualization in Looker.
Every time either in dev mode or not or when editing the dashboard if I adjust the size of the columns they will not stay that way when saving the dashboard. For example this is what it looks like where the name section is spaced way out.

Is there a way to lock in the spacing of column within looker visuals?

I am getting this:

[image]

I want this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike, you can also hard code the width for each column in the `Edit` section of the table chart:

[image]

Comment: Hey good call there. I never even noticed that before. That is actually better than my solution since you can specify exactly the size you want!

Answer (score 1):

Of coarse after posting a question on this I finally stumbled onto the option to freeze columns in the edit window. So instead of deleting my post I will just put my findings here so that if someone happens to have this problem they can find the answer here.

In the visualization edit window you can select the 3 vertical dots next to a column and freeze the column size. This works for all columns individually.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi there this is a known issue in Looker dashboards according to Looker support. The way to fix this is to adjust the fields width manually with your cursor in the Look before the visualization gets into Looker. Not ideal but it works.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, manually adjusting the column width still did not work for me. However, this issue was completely fixed by turning off the "Size Columns to Fit" toggle

[image: Size Columns to Fit toggle turned off in the series tab]